# Cannot connect to cpanel mySQL database in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, cpanel

I've created a database in cpanel and have added a user with all permissions to it as well. When I attempt to configure my Laravel project to the database, it says

> 'connection to localhost failed'

I've updated my .env file but when I configure it under deployment it can't connect. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Here is my .env code and my database.php with the names obviously changed.

```
//.env code:

    DB_CONNECTION=mysql
    DB_HOST=localhost
    DB_PORT=3306
    DB_DATABASE=mydbname
    DB_USERNAME=myusername
    DB_PASSWORD=mypassword

//database.php code:

    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'mydbname'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'myusername'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'mypassword'),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

and here are some screen shots:
[image: config]
[image: phpmyadmin]

If anyone can tell me what I am doing wrong that would be great.

Comment: You are trying to connect via SFTP!  mysql doesn't use SFTP protocol u_u

Comment: I'm a bit of a noob, which protocol should I be using?

Comment: You must use a mysql tool like mysql workbench

Comment: Also, be sure to add your IP to "Remote Connection" in cPanel. You can also use `*` as a wildcard.

Comment: okay, but can't I use phpmyadmin instead of workbench?